# How i replace voice to each edittext

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, voice

You see the 2 edittext so I think that when the cursor available on EditText I will make content in that EditText so how can implement this.

see image below.

[image]

Comment: You can see the picture when you click the description

Comment: please give more explanation.

Comment: Ok sir . I am doing with speech to text work so when i use many of edittext how can i manage this because  my work just make speech to text on one edittext

Comment: You wanted to read all EditTexts.

Comment: How it sir. So what function can i check the cursor on edittext

Comment: Thankyou so much sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way would be **TextWatcher** Listeners which will trigger when you click on edittext.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {  

        @Override  
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {  

        }  

        @Override  
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {  
            //enable your speech to text.
        }  

        @Override  
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {  

        }  
    });
```

Tell me what you think.